# Пройти авторизацию на сайте с хостинг (под видом браузера)

Tags: curl, php

Не могу пройти с помощью cUrl авторизацию на сайте ati.su

Господа эксперты, посмотрите, может я что-то неправильно делаю?

```
function request($url,$post = 0){
$ch = curl_init();
$ref="User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Widows NT)";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); // отправляем на 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // пустые заголовки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // возвратить то что вернул сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // следовать за редиректами
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);// таймаут4
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post!==0 ); // использовать данные в post
if($post) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
 $data = request('http://www.ati.su/Login/Login.aspx?checkcookie=1&ReturnUrl=%2fOffice%2fDefault.aspx');
$url = 'http://www.ati.su/Office/ExtraAuth.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fOffice%2fDefault.aspx&IsTwoFactorsRequired=true';
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data = str_get_html($data);
$auth = array(

    '__EVENTTARGET'=>'',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT'=>'',

    'tksm2_HiddenField'=>$data->find('input[name="tksm2_HiddenField"]',0)->value,
'__VIEWSTATE'=>$data->find('input[name="__VIEWSTATE"]',0)->value,
    'ctl00$ctl00$main$PlaceHolderMain$extLogin$ucLoginFormPage$tbLogin'=>'логин(на русском)',
'ctl00$ctl00$main$PlaceHolderMain$extLogin$ucLoginFormPage$tbPassword'=>'пароль(на русском)',
'ctl00$ctl00$main$PlaceHolderMain$extLogin$ucLoginFormPage$chbxRememberMe'=>'on',
'ctl00$ctl00$main$PlaceHolderMain$extLogin$ucLoginFormPage$btnPageLogin'=>'Вход в систему',
'ctl00$ctl00$main$Ccounters1$counterPageType'=>'default_page',
);
$data->clear();
unset($data);
echo iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8",$header) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

CURL для всего подойдет, думаю, значения куков вам все равно присваивает php скрипт, а JS просто обновляет контент, думаю, вы неправильно делаете что-то.

Comment: Пробовал отключать javascript на сайте. Поля отправки формы пустые получаются. Т.е. js присваивает нужные поля.

У меня все время выскакивает ошибка 401.

Comment: Смотрите запрос, который отправляется при авторизации руками, и сравнивайте его с тем, что отправляете в curl.

Comment: Я смотрю на выходе. Он не соответствует тому, что на входе.

Comment: Хм. Странно. Попробовал отключить js  в firefox,  и авторизация прошла без js и даже не дошла до аутентификации по телефону.